# bootstrap columns on mobile stacking up down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I am using `col-auto` and `col` to create a two column layout, where the first column behaves like the left sidebar and second column will store the content.

My problem is when I use `table` in the second column content area the column stacks up and down in mobile device.

below is a snippet to understand my situation.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto bg-primary">aaa</div>
    <div class="col bg-secondary">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the default behavior of bootstrap columns. How do you want it to display on mobile? Side by side the same as desktop?

Comment: @souzan yes same as desktop, fixed first column  and second column can vary in width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, I added `d-flex` and `flex-nowrap` in the `row`, now both columns are coming side by side but, on mobile devices a horizontal scroll bar is appearing. to overcome this I reduced the width of the column having content.

Below is the updated snippet

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex flex-nowrap">
      <div class="col-auto bg-primary">aaa</div>
      <div class="col bg-secondary" style="width:87%">
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td>sdasa</td>
                          <td>sdasa</td>
                          <td>sdasa</td>
                          <td>sdasa</td>
                          <td>sdasa</td>
                          <td>sdasa</td>
                          <td>sdasa</td>
                          <td>sdasa</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it to auto maybe give it a set size like this.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 bg-primary">aaa</div>
    <div class="col-9 bg-secondary">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                        <td>sdasa</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the first column to be fixed in width

Comment: okay you can swap the columns like this: 

`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 bg-primary">aaa</div>
    <div class="col bg-secondary">`

Comment: i edited my original answer so the sidebar is set in width and not the main content.

Comment: I want the width of first column to be according to content

Comment: @aje Have you tried wrapping it in a `container-fluid`?